# Having trouble with crash when performing .ondelete on a list (SwiftUI).. crashing in .onReceive for a timer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am having a problem with an app that I am making, that is crashing. I have been trying to hours to figure it out, but am stumped.

I have a list that holds multiple timers, that are all updated with .onReceive.

I have everything working... I can start and stop each timer, reset each timer, etc. However, when I try to use .onDelete on the list to remove a timer, I get a crash with "index out of range" in the .onReceive method.

```
List {
                ForEach(viewModel.initialTimeRemainingSeconds.indices, id: \.self) { time in
                    Section {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("\(viewModel.foodName[time])")
                                    .font(.title2.weight(.bold))
                                Text("\(viewModel.convertSecondsToTime(timeInSeconds: viewModel.timeRemainingSeconds[time]))")
                                    .font(.title2)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button {
                                viewModel.timeRemainingSeconds[time] = viewModel.initialTimeRemainingSeconds[time]
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "gobackward")
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            Button(viewModel.timerButtonTitle[time]) {
                                viewModel.timerStartAndStop(timerNumber: time)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .font(.title2)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(viewModel.timerButtonColor[time])
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        .onReceive(viewModel.timer) { _ in
                            if viewModel.timerStart[time] == true {
                                viewModel.timeRemainingSeconds[time] -= 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    viewModel.deleteItem(indexSet: indexSet)
                }
            }
```

I have an array of Bools that tells the .onReceive method if the timer should start or stop.

```
@Published var timerStart = [Bool]()
```

I tried using a second ForEach inside of the .onReceive method, but that causes a crash where swift takes too long to build... I guess the ForEach happening every call of .onReceive is too much for Xcode.

If I comment out the .onReceive, I can delete without a crash...

Comment: "causes a crash where swift takes too long to build" -- is this a runtime crash or a compile time error? It seems like you're describing two different things happening. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: You haven’t included the code for the view model but the fact that you are looping over the indices of one array while accessing another array with those indices inside the loop sounds problematic when removing elements. Most likely the two arrays get out of sync when you delete.

Comment: I edited the original post with the full View and ViewModel. It's definitely the arrays being out of sync. I just can't figure out why the if statement inside of .onReceive seems to not update when I delete. It's almost like .onReceive does the calculation in the if statement (which accesses the array), a full second before the publisher (the timer) triggers the .onReceive method. If that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you need so many arrays, why not create a struct with some (all?) of the properties you now store in separate arrays so you can have one array instead for them? Then maybe you wouldn’t need to loop using the indices but objects instead.

Comment: Yeah I know I need a model for the Timer with all of the properties, then an array of [TimerModel] in the viewmodel. Still learning, so wasn’t sure how exactly to implement it that way. The code above is what has worked, until now…

Comment: Don't use `indices` it is considered unsafe for this reason.

Comment: Using 0..<.count doesn't work either. It seems to have to do with the timer on the @main thread. If I comment out the .onReceive, everything works fine as far as the arrays go. The timers no longer work though.

Comment: Well, I ended up creating a Timer model, and changed all of the code so the TimerModel has all of the Timer properties, and the ViewModel has only one array of TimerModels. Still running into the same problem... .onReceive is crashing the app when I delete a TimerModel from the timerModelsArray.

Comment: Is the problem that all of the timers are running on the same Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()?

Comment: This is the actual problem code: .onReceive(viewModel.timer) { _ in
                                if viewModel.timerModelArray[time].timerStart == true {
                                    viewModel.timerModelArray[time].timeRemainingSeconds -= 1
                                }
                            }

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. Had to change timers to scheduled timers instead of published, which allowed me to call .invalidate() on the individual timer before deleting it from the Timer array. The timer was still running for the last tick even after deleting it, giving index out of range. Man that one was a pain.